# Determine the image of the unit circle $S^1$ by the action of the matrix $e^A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-exponential

We have:

$$e^{ \begin{pmatrix}
-5 & 9\\
-4 & 7
\end{pmatrix} }$$

I need to determine the image of the unit circle $S^1$ by the action of the matrix $e^A$.

I think that I know how to calculate $e^A$:

I get the Jordan decomposition:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
  -5 & 9\\
  -4 & 7
 \end{pmatrix}  =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -6 & 1\\
  -4 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1\\
  0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot
 \frac{1}{4}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1\\
  1 & -6
 \end{pmatrix}
 $$
With eigenvalues: $\lambda$ = 1, algebraic multiplicity = 2, eigenvecotrs: $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
  1\\
  0
 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
 0\\
 1
 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$
$$ \displaystyle e^A = \sum^{\infty}_{i = 0} \frac{A^i}{i!}$$
$$e^A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -6 & 1\\
  -4 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot
 \left(
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}
 +
 \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{i = 1} \frac{ \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1\\
  0 & 1
 \end{pmatrix}}{i!}
 \right)
 \cdot
 \frac{1}{4}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1\\
  1 & -6
 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$e^A = \begin{pmatrix}
  -5 & 9\\
  -4 & 7
 \end{pmatrix}  =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -6 & 1\\
  -4 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{i = 1} \frac{1}{i!}& \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{i = 1} \frac{2^{i-1}}{i!}\\
  0 & \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{i = 1} \frac{1}{i!}
 \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot
 \frac{1}{4}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1\\
  1 & -6
 \end{pmatrix}$$
Where: $$\displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{i = 1} \frac{2^{i-1}}{i!} = \frac{1}{2} \sum^{\infty}_{i = 1} \frac{2^{i}}{i!} = \frac{1}{2}(e^2 - 1)
 $$
So:
$$e^A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  -6 & 1\\
  -4 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot
 \begin{pmatrix}
  e & \displaystyle \frac{e^2}{2} - \displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\\
  0 & e
 \end{pmatrix}
 \cdot
 \frac{1}{4}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1\\
  1 & -6
 \end{pmatrix} =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \displaystyle \frac{-3e^2 + e + 3}{4} & \displaystyle \frac{9e^2 - 9}{2}\\
  \displaystyle \frac{-e^2 + 1}{2} & 3e^2 + e - 3
 \end{pmatrix}
 $$

Now, I don't know if I did it correctly up to this point and what I should do next - to operate on my unit circle.

---

Solution:

Because of @Oscar Lanzi we know that:
$$e^{\begin{pmatrix}-5 & 9\\-4 & 7\end{pmatrix}}=e\begin{pmatrix}-5 & 9\\-4 & 7\end{pmatrix}$$
Then because of that:
[Equation of unit circle under linear transformation - can't understand role of inverse matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444359/equation-of-unit-circle-under-linear-transformation-cant-understand-role-of-i)
(answer by @Prototank)
We know that the image of unit circle in action of the matrix $A$ is given by: $$65x^{2}-166xy+106y^{2}=1$$
Now we need to scale by $e$ and we get the image of unit circle in action of the matrix $e^A$:
$$65x^{2}-166xy+106y^{2}=e^2$$

Comment: There may be a more sophisticated way to do this, but have you tried a few key points on the unit circle and see if there's any obvious behavior?

Comment: No, I'm not sure I I would know how to do that.

Comment: For example, find the images of $(0,1), (1,0)$ etc. It also seems a mistake has been made somewhere, it seems like for your matrxi $A$, $\exp(A)=eA$, according to software: [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=matrix+exponential+%7B%7B-5%2C9%7D%2C%7B-4%2C7%7D%7D).

Comment: Ohh, I see. So having that exp(A) I should find the images of some points and look for a pattern?

Comment: Notice $\exp(A)=eA$ means that the action of $\exp(A)$ on any vector $v$ is basically the same as the action of $A$ on $v$, so what would $A$ do to a vector on the unit circle? Then scale it by factor of $e$.

Comment: As @just a user's answer points out, it is an ellipse. Here is the graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/umzmpcil68

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix exponentiation is much simpler than it looks. When you find that $1$ is the only eigenvalue, render

$\begin{pmatrix}-5 & 9\\-4 & 7\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-6 & 9\\-4 & 6\end{pmatrix}.$

The first matrix on the right just gives a factor of $e$ to the overall exponential. The second matrix is nilpotent and the series for its exponential is just

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}-6 & 9\\-4 & 6\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-5 & 9\\-4 & 7\end{pmatrix}.$

So

$e^{\begin{pmatrix}-5 & 9\\-4 & 7\end{pmatrix}}=e\begin{pmatrix}-5 & 9\\-4 & 7\end{pmatrix}.$

Continue from there.

Comment: I think I know what to do next. I will edit my original post soon.

Comment: I got it, I will post full answer.

Answer (score 4):

This address the general question of shape of image of an unit circle under the action of $e^A$. We can think of a linear dynamic system $\dot x=Ax$, the solution of which will be $x=e^{tA}$. Then what you are seeking is the ending position of points starting from the unit circle, after following linear dynamics for $t=1$.

[image]
[image]

---

This animation has credit to Ella Batty. I TAed her class last semester and used this as a demo for 2d dynamic systems.

https://twitter.com/i/status/1319061743679799297

Answer (score 2):

The calculation won't be easy, but standard.
To understand the image of any invertible matrix $T$ acting on the unit circle, first do the SVD decomposition $$T=U\Sigma V = U\begin{pmatrix} \sigma_1 & \\ & \sigma_2\end{pmatrix}V$$ Note that $V$ send the circle back to itself, as it keeps norms. Now it should be clear that the image is just an ellipse with two principal axes being $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ along the directions of the two column vectors of $U$.

Also to find $U$ and $\sigma_i$, we only have to diagonalize $TT^*$.